# Restrict <w:instrText> Field in Word OOXML

Tags: javascript, openxml, wordml, word-web-addins

I want to put important data in "w: fldChar" tag, I tried to put that data in "w:instrText" tag, but this code can be changed by user on run time, I want to restrict this field, is their any solution to that?

below is the code sample:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
     <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
     <w:instrText xml:space="preserve" >"{variable}"</w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
     <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
     <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: What kind of "important data" are you trying to store in the field?

Comment: I did it by using Content control in fields, they are acting like a place holder. and also hold some data.

Comment: The `w:fldChar` itself is a placeholder. `w:instrText` is the field code.